# Evaluate the surface integral over a cone region

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let $\omega = (xyz)dx +(xy^2)dy + (e^x)dz$ 
Evaluate $\int_S d\omega$ where $S$ is the cone with base $x^2+y^2 = 9$ in the xy plane and vertex at $(-2,3,1)$ oriented by the normal which points away from the center line. 
I am thinking of using the generalized Stokes theorem, so I am trying to find the $dS$ that bounds my surface; but I am having trouble parametrizing this boundary.. how do I parametrize this 2D shape? 
The cone is a surface of revolution $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2} = \frac{z^2}{c^2}$

Comment: You gotta write what you know , you're going to have to construct equation of the cone

Comment: Here is a quick idea though, $ x = 3 \cos t$ , $ y= 3 \sin t$ consider a point at height $z$ of cone, you can relate $z$ to $x$ and $y$

Comment: I guess polar coordinate is what we need here?

Comment: Why do you want polar? You can do in cartesian no problem. Have you tried drawing the cone?

Comment: Use Stokes' theorem and instead evaluate $ ~\displaystyle \int_{\partial S} \omega~ $. The boundary is the curve $x^2 + y^2 = 9, z = 0$